# The service is blocked

Tags: android, service, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm building a service that every times downlaod all the information of a BLE device and storage this data into a local database.

Now I'm building a service that do this jobs. If I try to start my application in debug from Android Studio it works never error. I'm try to do in background my application for 3 hours about, the service save all the information and the service is not locked.

Now, I'm building an APK file, I'm try to install it into the same Android device, but the service run only one times, after that it is not execute.

I'm using for test Samsung J3 with Android 7.0

What is my problem ?

This is my BlePowerService.java:

```
public class BlePowerService extends Service {
    public DbLayer db;
    Setting settingApp;
    List<ScanFilter> filters;
    String[] stringSequence = new String[] {CHARACTERISTIC_FORZA_STRING, CHARACTERISTIC_TEMPERATURA_STRING};
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothGatt mGatt;
    BluetoothDevice currDevice;
    static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 500;
    static String SPLIT_CHAR =";";
    BluetoothLeScanner mLEScanner;
    Handler mHandler;
    int ReadQueueIndex;
    List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> ReadQueue;
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic caratteristicaDaLeggere;
    ScanSettings settings;
    Integer ultimaForzaLetta,ultimaTemperaturaLetta;
    boolean continuaLetturaForza, continuaLetturaTemperatura;
    boolean isReading = true;
    String LOG_CODE = "NOTIFSRV";
    GattClientCallback gattClientCallback;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;


    public BlePowerService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mHandler = new Handler();

        Context sharedContext = null;
        try {
            sharedContext = this.createPackageContext(
                    "com.care.devicesensor",
                    Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE);
            if (sharedContext == null) {
                return;
            }
            db=new DbLayer(sharedContext);
            db.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String error = e.getMessage();
          //  Log.d(LOG_CODE,"DB error : " + error);
            return;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {
            //RECUPERO LE IMPOSTAZIONI SETTATE DALL'UTENTE
            settingApp = db.fetchSetting();
            if (settingApp != null && settingApp.getAddressBleSX()!=null) {
                //POSSO FILTRARE DIRETTAMENTE PER L'UUID DEL DISPOSITIVO MEMORIZZATO
                //DALL'UTENTE
                ScanFilter.Builder scanFilterMac =
                        null;
                    scanFilterMac = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress(settingApp.getAddressBleSX());
                if(filters==null)
                    filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
                //if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                filters.add(scanFilterMac.build());
                //}
                //FILTRO ANCHE PER LA CARATTERISTICA DI FORZA
                ScanFilter filter = null;
                    filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString(CHARACTERISTIC_FORZA_STRING)).build();
                filters.add(filter);

                final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                        (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
                    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
                //mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                    mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
                    settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER)
                            .build();
                scanLeDevice(true);
                mTimer = new Timer();
                //ogni 2 ore
                continuaLetturaForza = true;
                continuaLetturaTemperatura = true;

                int nSecondi = settingApp.getFrequenzaDownload()!= null ? settingApp.getFrequenzaDownload() : 1;
                //mTimer.schedule(timerTask, 10000, 1000 * nSecondi);
                mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate (timerTask, 10000, 1000 * nSecondi);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
           // Log.e("POWER_SERVICE", e.getMessage());
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private Timer mTimer;

    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //LEGGO TUTTI I DATI DAL SENSORE FINCHE CI SONO VALORI
             int counter = 0;
            while(continuaLetturaForza || continuaLetturaTemperatura){
                counter++;
                //Log.v("CICLO WHILE", counter+"");
                if (currDevice != null) {

                    if(ReadQueue!= null && ReadQueue.size()>0){
                        int index =0;
                        for(index=0; index < ReadQueue.size(); index++){
                            if(mGatt!=null){
                                isReading = mGatt.readCharacteristic(ReadQueue.get(index));
                                while(isReading){
                                    try {
                                        Thread.sleep(1);
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }else{
                                continuaLetturaForza = false;
                                continuaLetturaTemperatura = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
              }else{
                    //provo a ricollegarmi al dispositivo probabile, abbia perso la connessione con esso
                    scanLeDevice(true);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(currDevice == null && counter == 25){
                        //in questo caso non è riuscito a trovare il dispositivo BLE
                        //esco dal ciclo
                        continuaLetturaForza = false;
                        continuaLetturaTemperatura = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
             if(gattClientCallback!=null && mGatt != null)
                gattClientCallback.disconnectGattServer();

        }

        public void stopTask() {

            if (timerTask != null) {

                Log.d("TIMER", "timer canceled");
                timerTask.cancel();
            }
        }
    };


    public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        //VERIFICO SE IL DEVICE è QUELLO CHE VOGLIO IO
        if (mGatt == null && settingApp != null
                && device.getAddress().equals(settingApp.getAddressBleSX())) {
            currDevice = device;
            gattClientCallback = new GattClientCallback();
            mGatt = currDevice.connectGatt(getBaseContext(), false, gattClientCallback);
            scanLeDevice(false);// will stop after first device detection
        }
    }

    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
                                     byte[] scanRecord) {
                    Handler h = new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
                    // Although you need to pass an appropriate context
                    h.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                          //  Log.i("onLeScan", device.toString());
                                connectToDevice(device);

                        }
                    });
                }
            };

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                    } else {
                        mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);

                    }
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            } else {
                mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
            }
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            } else {
                mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
            }
        }
    }


    private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
           // Log.i("callbackType", String.valueOf(callbackType));
           // Log.i("result", result.toString());
            BluetoothDevice btDevice = null;
               btDevice = result.getDevice();
            connectToDevice(btDevice);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            for (ScanResult sr : results) {
                Log.i("ScanResult - Results", sr.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
           Log.e("Scan Failed", "Error Code: " + errorCode);
        }
    };

    private class GattClientCallback extends BluetoothGattCallback {

        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            try{
                super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
                //Log.i("tag", "onConnectionStateChange newState: " + newState);

                if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_FAILURE) {
                    Log.e("ERROR_SERVICE", "Connection Gatt failure status " + status);
                    if(mGatt == null){

                    }else{
                        try {
                            gatt.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("", "close ignoring: " + e);
                        }
                        mGatt = null;
                    }
                    return;
                } else if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                    // handle anything not SUCCESS as failure
                    Log.e("ERROR_SERVICE", "Connection not GATT sucess status " + status);
                    if(mGatt == null){

                    }else{
                        try {
                            gatt.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("", "close ignoring: " + e);
                        }
                        mGatt = null;
                    }
                    return;
                }

                if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    //Log.i("INFO", "Connected to device " + gatt.getDevice().getAddress());
                    gatt.discoverServices();
                } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                    Log.i("INFO", "Disconnected from device");
                    if(mGatt == null){

                    }else{
                        try {
                            mGatt.close();
                            mGatt = null;
                            currDevice = null;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("", "close ignoring: " + e);
                        }
                        mGatt = null;
                    }

                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
                continuaLetturaForza = true;
                continuaLetturaTemperatura = true;
            }
        }

        public void disconnectGattServer() {
            //Log.i("INFo", "Closing Gatt connection");
            //  clearLogs();
            //mConnected = false;
            //mEchoInitialized = false;
            continuaLetturaForza = true;
            continuaLetturaTemperatura = true;
            isReading = false;
            if (mGatt == null) {

            }
            else{
                try{
                    mGatt.disconnect();
                   // mGatt.close();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    mGatt = null;
                }

            }
            //mGatt = null;
            //currDevice = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);

            if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
             //   Log.i("INFO", "Device service discovery unsuccessful, status " + status);
                return;
            }

            List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> matchingCharacteristics =
                    BluetoothUtils.findCharacteristics(gatt,stringSequence);
            if (matchingCharacteristics.isEmpty()) {
              //  Log.e("ERROR_SERVICE","Unable to find characteristics.");
                return;
            }else {

                //INIZIALIZZO LA LISTA DI CARATTERISTICHE CHE DEVO ANDARE A LEGGERE
                ReadQueue = new ArrayList<>();
                for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characterist : matchingCharacteristics) {
                    ReadQueue.add(characterist);
                }
                //ReadQueueIndex = 0;
                //ReadCharacteristics(ReadQueueIndex);
            }



        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
              String valoreRestituito = characteristic.getStringValue(0);
                if(valoreRestituito==null){
                    int i = 0;
                    i = i + 1;
                    return;
                }
                //SPLITTO PER IL CARATTERE ;
                String[] arrayValori = valoreRestituito.split(SPLIT_CHAR);
                //1 valore è l ID
                try{
                    int id = new Integer(arrayValori[0]);
                    //VERIFICO SE STO LEGGENDO TEMPERATURA O FORZA
                    if(characteristic.getUuid().equals(CHARACTERISTIC_FORZA_UUID)){
                        /*Log.v("CARATTERISTICA", "*****************************************");
                        Log.v("FORZA", "*****************************************");*/
                        if(ultimaForzaLetta!= null && ultimaForzaLetta == id){
                            continuaLetturaForza = false;
                            isReading = false;
                            return;
                        }
                        ultimaForzaLetta = id;
                    }else if(characteristic.getUuid().equals( CHARACTERISTIC_TEMPERATURA_UUID)){
                        /*Log.v("CARATTERISTICA", "*****************************************");
                        Log.v("TEMPERATURA", "*****************************************");*/
                        if(ultimaTemperaturaLetta!= null && ultimaTemperaturaLetta == id){
                            continuaLetturaTemperatura = false;
                            isReading = false;
                            return;
                        }
                        ultimaTemperaturaLetta = id;
                    }

                    SensorData mSenData = new SensorData();
                    mSenData.setIdType(id);
                    mSenData.setValue1(arrayValori[1]);
                    mSenData.setValue2(arrayValori[2]);
                    mSenData.setValue3(arrayValori[3]);
                    mSenData.setValue4(arrayValori[4]);
                    mSenData.setValue5(arrayValori[5]);
                    mSenData.setValue6(arrayValori[6]);
                    mSenData.setValue7(arrayValori[7]);
                    mSenData.setValue8(arrayValori[8]);
                    //TO-DO HO COMMENTATO QUESTA RIGA DI CODICE
                    // mSenData.setIdType(st.getId());
                    mSenData.setCharacteristic(characteristic.getUuid().toString());
                    mSenData.setValueTimestamp(db.getDateTime(true));
                    //inserisco i dati nel db
                        db.insertSensorData(mSenData);

                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent("update"));

                    //EventBus.getDefault().post(new UnfriendEvent(userId));
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
                }
                isReading = false;

            } else {
                isReading = false;
                Log.e("ERROR_SERVICE", "Characteristic read unsuccessful, status: " + status);
               disconnectGattServer();

                return;
            }
        }

    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        try {
            db.close();
            Log.d(LOG_CODE,"DB connection closed" );

            mTimer.cancel();
            timerTask.cancel();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Job Scheduler instead of service. Modern apps can perform many of their tasks asynchronously, outside the direct flow of user interaction.

> If your app targets Android 5.0 (API level 21), we recommend that you use the JobScheduler to execute background tasks..

For further details check android documentation below

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling